# Flushing a sequence of Angular HTTP TestRequest

Tags: angular, async-await, angular-httpclient

I have an `async` function that needs to make a `POST` request, but some of the data must be fetched from the server first:

```
async createObject() {
  // HTTP request #1: dep1 is needed for the second request
  const dep1 = await this.http.get("/urlA")
    .pipe(first())
    .toPromise();
  // Create the request object out of dep1 and some additional values
  const req = mkCreateParams(this.name, dep1);
  // HTTP request #2: Build something
  const res = await this.http.post("/urlB")
    .pipe(first())
    .toPromise();
  // When everything is done: Navigate away
  this.router.navigateByUrl(`/urlC/${res.id}`);

  return res;
}
```

I use the following code to test this:

```
const httpTesting = TestBed.inject(HttpTestingController);
const req = testInstance.createObject();

httpTesting
  .expectOne("/urlA")
  .flush({ /* ... SNIP ... */);

const generatedId = "f9f64792-0ceb-4e3c-ae7b-4c7a8af6a552";
httpTesting
  .expectOne({ method: "POST", url: "/urlB" })
  .flush({ id: generatedId });

const res = await req;
expect(res.id).toEqual(generatedId);
```

This fails immediatly when expecting `/urlB` and doesn't even reach the line where `res` is resolved. The error message is as follows:

```
Expected one matching request for criteria "Match method: POST, URL: /urlB", found none.
```

This seems to be because a request must have been already issued when calling `HttpTestingController.expectOne()`. As promises are resolved eagerly in JavaScript, the first request has already been made but the second request not.

Is there a way to tell the Angular `HttpTestingController` to relax a little and wait for the request to come by some time later? The existance of `HttpTestingController.verify` hints at this, but I have no idea how to get into a state where it would be useful.

Comment: Put breakpoint on retun res. What is value?

Comment: Execution does not reach that line

Comment: Ok back up to entry in that routine set breakpoint and tell me what you discover. It could be due to the navigate pre-empting the work flow and moving to that page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think waiting for the promises can help you, try `fixture.whenStable()`.

```
it('your title here', async done => {
  const httpTesting = TestBed.inject(HttpTestingController);
  const req = testInstance.createObject();

  httpTesting
    .expectOne("/urlA")
    .flush({ /* ... SNIP ... */);
  await fixture.whenStable(); // wait for the pending promises to resolve before proceeding
  const generatedId = "f9f64792-0ceb-4e3c-ae7b-4c7a8af6a552";
  httpTesting
    .expectOne({ method: "POST", url: "/urlB" })
    .flush({ id: generatedId });
  await fixture.whenStable(); // wait for the pending promises to resolve before proceeding
  const res = await req;
  expect(res.id).toEqual(generatedId);
  // call done to let Jasmine know you're done with this test
  done();
});
```